# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common is not working in IIS 8.5 but its working in IIS 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, dll

**I have deployed my web application using by Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common dll and hosted in IIS 7.0 and its working fine (Able to access the DB) but same published code i am deploying in IIS 8.5 but its not working and i am getting bellow error.**

ERROR System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

Comment: Check do you have correct version or not as per error. Check for 32 bit, 64 bit enviornment.

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question - but posting here for anyone looking for an answer.

Recently ran into this issue but with a Windows Service (of a legacy code/service). All we were trying to do was switch the Database server in the connection string from Server A to Server B.

Found the root cause to be that the SQL Authentication user id was not setup in Server B - seems obvious except that the error message wasn't. Anyways fixing the authentication issue addressed this exception for us.